# Login custom route being rejected by Auth

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

```
Router::scope('/:club_slug', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
});
```

So when I'm trying access `http://example.com/club-name/login`, I'm being redirected to `http://example.com/users/login` with the flash message `You have to login to access this area`.

Auth `loginAction` is `[controller => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']`, since the custom route that I mentioned at beginning of the question is pointing to the path that is specified at `loginAction` I thought the route will know that I'm talking about the same thing but is not what is happening.

Comment: First question, is `User` just a mistake in this code example, or does the login action really use the singular name as opposed to the plural one in your route?

Comment: just a mistake, I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic route elements are not being added/recognized automatically, you'll either have to persist them using either the `persist` option (applies only to that specific route):

```
Router::scope('/:club_slug', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect(
        '/login',
        ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'],
        ['persist' => ['club_slug']]
    );
});
```

or URL filters (affects all routes that are using a `club_slug` element):

```
Router::addUrlFilter(function ($params, $request) {
    if (isset($request->params['club_slug']) && !isset($params['club_slug'])) {
        $params['club_slug'] = $request->params['club_slug'];
    }
    return $params;
});
```

or you have to pass the element to your login action manually (this would match the `club_slug` route regardless of the current URL):

```
'loginAction' => [
    'controller' => 'Users',
    'action' => 'login',
    'club_slug' => 'club-slug' // wherever it may have come from
]
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Creating Persistent URL Parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-persistent-url-parameters)**
- **[API > Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder::connect()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Routing.RouteBuilder.html#_connect)**

Comment: In my case the second one was better