# CakePHP 4 - Admin prefix routing with i18n language parameter

Tags: cakephp, routes, internationalization, cakephp-4.x

I have cakephp4.2 project, i have implemented multilanguage approach where current language is sept in session. urls are same for all languages.

I want to add language parameter in url also.  I tried below code in `config/routes.php` file it is working for normal (non-admin-prefix) urls. but not working for `Admin` prefixed urls.

```php
use Cake\Routing\RouterBuilder;

$routes->setRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

$routes->scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
    $builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Clients', 'action' => 'index']);

    $builder->connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('language' => 'en|ar'));
    $builder->connect('/:language/:controller', array('action' => 'index'), array('language' => 'en|ar'));
    $builder->connect('/:language', array('controller' => 'Clients', 'action' => 'index'), array('language' => 'en|ar')) ;

    $builder->fallbacks();
});

$routes->prefix('Admin', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    //added below line for language but it is not working
    //$routes->connect('/:language', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'), array('language' => 'en|ar')) ;
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

working urls

```
localhost/cake4-lng/     
localhost/cake4-lng/en    
localhost/cake4-lng/ar    
localhost/cake4-lng/en/controller    
localhost/cake4-lng/admin/users/dashboard /*notice there is no language param with Admin*/
```

non-working url

```
localhost/cake4-lng/en/admin/users/dashboard    
localhost/cake4-lng/ar/admin/users/dashboard
```

ERROR on above 2 urls is:

> AdminController could not be found.

Comment: The commented out admin route in your config is only for the `login` action, but your list of sample URLs mentions the `dashboard` action.

Comment: there any controllers and actions in my project, I want something general I did for non-admin-prefix

Comment: I'm no routing expert, so I can't help with that. I just wondered if the reason why your `dashboard` URL didn't work was because you didn't set up an admin route for it, only for `login`.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, whenever you have routing problems, check `bin/cake routes` to see what routes are connected in wich way exactly.

That being said, you are connecting the routes with the `:language` element inside of the prefix, so your URLs cannot be `/en/admin/...`, but only `/admin/en/...`. In order to achieve the former, you'd have to wrap your prefix in a scope with the language element accordingly, something along the lines of this:

```php
$routes->scope('/:language', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->prefix('Admin', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $patterns = ['language' => 'en|ar'];
        
        $routes
            ->connect('/:controller/:action/*', [])
            ->setPatterns($patterns);
        $routes
            ->connect('/:controller', ['action' => 'index'])
            ->setPatterns($patterns);
        $routes
            ->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'])
            ->setPatterns($patterns);
    });
});
```

That would result in templates like `/:language/admin/...` being connected.

Comment: it says Undefined variable: routes on line `$routes->prefix('Admin', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {`

Comment: now it says: Missing Route ` A route matching "array ( 'prefix' => 'Admin', 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin' => NULL, '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found.`

Comment: I don't see the `language` key in that array, so I'd say that error is expected, and the URL array is incorrect.

Comment: the passwed context was `['_scheme' => 'http',
'_host' => 'localhost',
'_port' => null,
'_base' => '/alampk4lng',
'params' => [
'language' => 'ar',
'controller' => 'Admin',
'pass' => [ ],
'action' => 'index',
'plugin' => null,
'_matchedRoute' => '/:language/:controller',
'_ext' => null,
],]`

Comment: I'm not sure what the context has to do with it, or where exactly the error stems from. Check the stacktrace to figure from where exactly the problem is triggered, I would still suspect a URL array that is missing the `language` key (`params` is something different, that's the parsed results, not something that is being matched).

Comment: it seem I not tracing correctly can you please see my routes and error page. error: http://demo.alampk.com/cake4/error.html and rotes.php: http://demo.alampk.com/cake4/routes.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233552/discussion-between-alamnaryab-and-ndm).

Comment: The problem is the URL array that is used in `Application.php` on line `142` (second entry in the stacktrace). You may want to try persisting the language parameter, see https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#configuring-route-options and https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#creating-persistent-url-parameters, also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239834/login-custom-route-being-rejected-by-auth/30241270#30241270.

Comment: still not able to fix

Answer (score 0):

partially done
URLs are now working with language parameters, but links are not populated with language parameter using HTML helper.
eg.

`echo $this->Html->link('test',['controller'=>'clients','action'=>'index']);`
generates html as below without language  parameter
`<a href="/clients/index">test</a>`
while i need
`<a href="/en/clients/index">test</a>` or
`<a href="/ar/clients/index">test</a>`

I added below code in routes.php for admin routing

```
$routes->prefix('Admin', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/:language', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'), array('language' => 'en|ar')) ;
    $routes->connect('/:language/:controller', array('action' => 'index'), array('language' => 'en|ar'));
    $routes->connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('language' => 'en|ar'));

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    //$routes->connect('/:language', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'), array('language' => 'en|ar')) ;
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

and in appCotroller.php

```
public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event){       
    parent::beforeFilter($event); 
    $Session = $this->request->getSession(); 
    $urlLang = $this->request->getParam('language');
    if($urlLang!=null && in_array(strtolower($urlLang),['en','ar'])){
        $lng_val = strtolower($urlLang)=='ar'?'ar_AE':'en_us';
        $Session->write('Config.language',$lng_val);
    } 
    if($Session->check('Config.language')){
        I18n::setLocale($Session->read('Config.language'));
    }else{
        $Session->write('Config.language','ar_AE');
    } 
}

public function changeLanguage($language=null){
    $Session = $this->request->getSession(); 
    if($language!=null && in_array($language,['en_US','ar_AE'])){
        $Session->write('Config.language',$language);
        return $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
    else
    {
        $Session->write('Config.language',I18n::locale());
        return $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
}
```